# How to add a pop up/Dialog box and pass information back to the class in Android

Tags: android, database, dialog

I am trying to create a pop-up dialog to allow the user of my android app to add a new field to a list on their main page. 
I've done a bit of research and found the Dialog/alertDialog option, but i haven't been able to get it working correctly.

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listView;
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
//final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); //!!! ERROR HERE !!! //

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Button AddNewStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddNew);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    //db.addStudentProfile(new StudentProfile("Shannon", "White"));
    //db.addStudentProfile(new StudentProfile(1,"Shannon", "White", "WhitehousePS", "30", "21" ));       

    /*AddNewStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Using an alertDialog to get the user to enter in a new Student

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_new_student);
        dialog.setTitle("Add a new student");
        final EditText firstName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        final EditText surname=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        final EditText school=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.school);
        final EditText age=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
        Button save=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button btnCancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        dialog.show();
    }
});*/

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<StudentProfile> contacts = db.getAllStudents();       

    for (StudentProfile studProf : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: "+studProf.getID()+" , First name: " + studProf.getFirstName() + ", Surname: " + studProf.getSurname() + ", School: " + studProf.getSchool() + 
                ", Reading Level: "+ studProf.getReadingLevel() + ", Age: " + studProf.getAge();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }

    db.getAllStudents();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

It's linked to a very simple xml page that just has editible text fields. 
My application won't even open with this code - i have tracked the issue down to this line:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

at the top of my program.

IS this the best way to go about making a pop up dialog?
Also, what is the easiest way to pass the information back to the class to be stored in a database?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Hi there, there is a lot you can simplify for now change final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);  to final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this); and see if it works

Comment: @KevinCrain - I just tried that, it didn't work I'm afraid, the app still stops when run :( 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention you should call it in the OnCreate method not were you have it currently :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create some private variables at the top of your class, and get the text from the editText and put it into those variables in the dialog's button click handler method (where you have the 'sign in the user' comment.)

Sometimes it's also easyer to crate a dialog themed activity.